# Addressing to subsequent objects in loop function in R

Tags: r, loops

I need to create a loop function in which I need to address to subsequent objects which names end with numbers i.e. object1, object 2, object3. So the code should look like this:

```
object1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
object2 <- c(2,3,4,5,6)
object3 <- c(3,4,5,6,7)

for (i in 1:3) {
    assign (paste0("new_object",i), mean(object???))
}
```

So I need a equivalent to just typing

```
new_object1 <- mean(object1)
new_object2 <- mean(object2)
new_object3 <- mean(object3)
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

It would be `get` to return the values of that object by `paste`ing the 'i' with the 'object' string

```
for (i in 1:3) {
  assign(paste0("new_object",i), mean(get(paste0('object', i)))
 }
```

But, it is not a recommended way as it is creating new objects in the global env.

---

Instead, if the intention is to get the `mean` of all the 'object's,

```
sapply(mget(paste0("object", 1:3)), mean)
```

Or if there are more than three, use `ls` with `pattern`

```
sapply(mget(ls(pattern = '^object\\d+$')), mean)
```

Here, `mget` returns the value of more than one objects in a `list`, loop through the `list` with `sapply` and apply the `mean` function on the `list` element.

---

Creating objects can also be done from the `list` with `list2env`

```
out <- lapply( mget(ls(pattern = '^object\\d+$')), mean)
names(out) <- paste0('new_', names(out))
list2env(out, .GlobalEnv) # not recommended based on the same reason above
```